# Lifecycle of an Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am having an application with a register activity. When I registered succesfully a new acitivty shows up. but when I am clicking back the register activity appears again.

I have the followin tags:

```
next_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

And what I have is that

```
A-->B-->D (when closing D, A shows up)
```

and I want is to open the new activity to the top, closing all the previous ones

```
A-->B-->D //  D--> Close APP
```

So the final behaviour have to be that:

```
A --> B (from B can navigate from A)
B --> C (When C is created the other ones has to dissapear).
C       (When created from B).
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set `android:noHistory="true"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` or start the activity by adding the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` flag to the `Intent` used to start the activity you don't want to keep in the history.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Comment: The problem is that when I click back button from B I want to go to A, but when I call D I want the other ones disapperead.

Comment: This is important information missing from your question, if you could update the question to include this additional flow (A -> B, Back takes to A, A -> B -> C, Back closes app).

Comment: If you are using API Level 11 or higher you might have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME

Comment: I have tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME but the A activity is still showing up :S

Answer (score 0):

Since the closing of Activity A is dependent on the success of Activity B, you could use `startActivityForResult` and then navigate to Activity C directly from A.

Activity A:

```
public static final int REGISTER_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

public void onRegisterButtonClick(View v) {
    startActivityForResult(
            new Intent(this, ActivityB.class), REGISTER_REQUEST_CODE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REGISTER_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Assuming you've logged your user in in ActivityB... (otherwise you could grab login credentials from the intent)
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityC.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

And in Activity B:

```
// User finishes registration process...
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP works for me. This should work:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
```

Or you can try with onBackPressed. You can do something like this:

```
     boolean boolExit =false;
//back button
        @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
                {
                    if (!boolExit)
                    {

                        boolExit= true;
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // exit application


                        Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityD.class);

                        startActivity(i);

                        finish();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
                }
            }
```

And you can finish every Activity you want.